# Подскажите, как объединить два SQL запроса в один?

Tags: java, jdbc

У меня есть два sql-запроса для двух разных таблиц:

```
PreparedStatement fileStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE FILE_ SET STORAGE_ID = ? WHERE FILE_ID = " + file.getId() + "");
PreparedStatement storageStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE STORAGE_ SET FORMAT_SUPPORTED = ?,COUNTRY_STORAGE = ?, SIZE_STORAGE = ? WHERE STORAGE_ID = " + storage.getId()+ "")
```

Мне надо минимизировать количество обращений к базе.Как их объединить в один запрос ?

Answer (score 1):

Подготовленные вопросы можно объединять, если они выполняются для одной таблицы:

```
String sql = "UPDATE FILE_ SET STORAGE_ID = ? WHERE FILE_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setInt(1, 42);
stmt.setInt(2, 13);
stmt.addBatch();

stmt.setInt(1, 1);
stmt.setInt(2, 100);
stmt.addBatch();

stmt.executeBatch();
```

Если требуется "пакетировать" запросы для разных таблиц, то от их подготовки придётся отказаться:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.addBatch("UPDATE FILE_ SET STORAGE_ID = " + 42 + " WHERE FILE_ID = " + 13);
stmt.addBatch("UPDATE STORAGE_ SET FORMAT_SUPPORTED = 1, COUNTRY_STORAGE = 2, SIZE_STORAGE = 3 WHERE STORAGE_ID = 4");
stmt.executeBatch();
```

Или можно засунуть оба запроса в одну транзакцию:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
try {
    fileStatement.execute();
    storageStatement.execute();
    connection.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    connection.rollback();
}
```

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, сейчас у меня эти два запроса и находятся в одной транзакции... я хочу объединить их в один запрос, если такое возможно ... а возможно или нет, я не знаю ((  таблицы между собой связаны внешним ключом

Comment: @YuriiS все возможные способы "объединения" я вам уже показал, других нет.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, а можно эти два запроса сделать в одном PreparedStatement ?

Comment: На сколько я помню, нельзя.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, я сейчас попробовал сделать как Вы показали stmt.executeBatch(); и падает ошибка `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ошибка при пакетировании: ORA-00927: отсутствует знак равенства` что я мог не правильно сделать ?

Comment: Судя по ошибке, где-то в запросе отсутствует знак равенства.

Comment: Проверял это, вроде все знаки равенства стоят... Наверное в запросе что-то не так пишу

Comment: И Statement в данной ситуации не подходит, так как я работаю с данными объекта. Надо использовать PreparedStatement

Comment: Тогда вам остаётся довольствоваться транзакцией.